# Blender rendering fileformat: .file

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, file-format

So i have made a video and i started rendering in AVI format, codec H.264 with MP3 audio and when I'm finished rendering it's just a .file file. If I open it using windows media player it runs, sometimes.

Ps: I'm saving it as a H.264 and i have used it before...

***Extra information:***

- **Video Format:**
- 720p (1280x720)
- 50 FPS
- Raw video from a USB 2.0
- Raw video format: 720p (1280x720) 50 FPS Bitrate: 4785 AVCHD-video
- **Encoding:**
- Format:AVI
- Codec:H.264
- Bitrate:6000
- GOP Size:18

Comment: Um what are you saving it as....? As long as the format is valid you could just manually change the extension.

Comment: H.264, but i have used the exact same setup before and it worked...

Comment: That is quite odd! could you upload a .blend with a service like http://pasteall.org/blend so I can take a look?

Comment: Sure! Just a monet...

Comment: It doesn't want to upload... :/

Comment: Try filedropper.com

Comment: There we go:http://www.filedropper.com/filmprojekt

Comment: ...looks correct to me, could be a bug :/

Comment: uuuurrr... And I have a deadline for a vid...
Well thanks any way :)

Comment: Have you tried manually changing the file extension? You'll need to make sure that windows doesn't hide file types from you. Just right click, rename file, and add the extension yourself, whatever you originally rendered. If you don't see file extensions go here : (http://www.pcworld.com/article/241051/how_to_view_hidden_files_and_file_extensions_in_windows.html)

Comment: You should render your animations as a video sequence. This has several advantages. If your render crashed, you will not have to re-render from frame 1. You can always convert the image sequence to a video later.